# Why doesn't href from HTML to CSS work correctly with Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, href

I have the next problem:

Im ceating a basic django webpage using HTML and CSS. The issue is that when I try to make the href from the HTML file to the CSS one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modelado.css">
```

It doesn't work correctly. my HTML file called "inicio.html" and "modelado.css" are in the same folder, but once I make the href, the console says this:

Not Found: /inicio/modelado.css

I think that the console is trying to find a folder called "inicio", but that's impossible since inicio is the HTML file from where I am running the program.
What I want to know is if there is another way to write the direction, because that directory doesn't exist.
I also think that this is a django related problem, because when I only use HTML, that line of code actually works when the files are in the same folder.

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. You need to store the css file into static folder and do the static settings in your project settings.py file and load the static and file in the html. [Refer this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is not a dynamic file (it is static) so by using

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'yourstyle.css' %}">
```

you can load static files (like css).

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial06/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll add that you also have to add the directory to a variable called STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py, but if I wouldn't have got your answer, I would have taken much more time to find it, thank you!